# Gitlab on archlinux not working -> API not reachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab, archlinux

I have tried to install gitlab on archlinux following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gitlab 
As 8080 is a well current port, I have switched to 8033.

When I try to connect to the website, it prints me 402 error.
If I have a look to nginx/gitlab_errors.log I have :

```
2015/03/23 21:16:00 [error] 29748#0: *1081 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.51.59.153, server: gitlab.floth.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8033/", host: "gitlab.floth.fr"
```

If I open `/var/lib/gitlab/gitlab-shell.log` I get

```
# Logfile created on 2015-03-23 21:09:06 +0100 by logger.rb/47272
W, [2015-03-23T21:09:06.321779 #30833]  WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET http://localhost:8033/api/v3/internal/check>: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8033>
W, [2015-03-23T21:17:48.059769 #31230]  WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET http://localhost:8033//api/v3/internal/check>: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8033>
W, [2015-03-23T21:22:01.846281 #31548]  WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <GET http://localhost:8033//api/v3/internal/check>: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8033>
```

And if I run `sudo -u gitlab bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` I get :

```
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /usr/share/webapps/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED: Failed to connect to internal API
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u gitlab -H editor /usr/share/webapps/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished
```

If I do netstat -a | grep 8033, nothing listening on that port...

Does anyone have an idea where to look for ? What service is not running because not started or failed?
Thank you for your help.

---

Edit 
Content of `gitlab-shell/config.yml`

```
user: gitlab
gitlab_url: "http://localhost:8033/"

repos_path: "/srv/git/gitlab"

auth_file: "/var/lib/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"

redis:
  bin: /usr/bin/redis-cli
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 6379
  database: 0
  namespace: resque:gitlab

log_file: "/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell.log"
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
git_annex_enabled: false
```

Comment: It seems that gitlab-shell is failing. Could you paste the content of your gitlab-shell's `config.yml` ? This file is where you choose the git's repo path; the ssl settings, the gitlab's url for API, the hostname of your redis etc. You can refer to [this file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/config.yml.example) for an example

Comment: Hi jeanMarcAssin, sorry for the time it took me to answer. Added to my first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TADA !
I found where my configuration was bad.
All comes from the fact I have chosen an other port than 8080.
In such a case, it is important not only to modify gitlab-shell configuration (that is only the client) but the server part `gitlab/config/unicorn.rb`:

```
# Listen on both a Unix domain socket and a TCP port.
# If you are load-balancing multiple Unicorn masters, lower the backlog
# setting to e.g. 64 for faster failover.
listen "/run/gitlab/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 1024
listen "127.0.0.1:8033", :tcp_nopush => true
```