# GitLab: can not create group using APIs

Tags: curl, nginx, gitlab

I'm trying to create a group using GitLab APIs by calling `POST`method on `/groups` using the admin account as mentioned in the following [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html)

Here is the curl command I use to test the API:

`curl -L -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: {token}" -X POST --data "name=TestGroup&path=TestGroup&description=TestGroup" https://{server}/api/v3/groups`

The result I got is `{"message":"404 Not Found"}`, However when I try to call `GET` on the same URL it works and I get list of all groups.

Note that the error message is returned as part of the response in a json, not as a status code. So it seems like it's received by the application.

The server is running behind a Nginx reverse proxy. To be sure this isn't the cause, I've setup an SSH tunnel to port 3000 and tried `http://localhost/api/v3/groups` too, but with the same error. Other endpoints worked fine in both scenarios.

Comment: In `gitlab-shell` configuration there is a file called `config.yml`, you can see an example [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/config.yml.example). Inside this file you have a parameter which looks like `gitlab_url: "http://localhost:8080/"`. This parameter is the one used for the API call, maybe you need to adjust it. You can also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29315524/1503683) for the unicorn config if you are using it

Comment: Did you try transferring a project to a group with the API as well? I'm stuck at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30311533/571461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem, I was creating a new group with the same name as an existing one but instead of getting a meaningful error message I got `{"message":"404 Not Found"}`